# What if an object is approaching us at near the speed of light?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light

Suppose an object that is 100 light years away is approaching us at 0.99c. It would take about 100.1 years for the object to reach Earth. But the light that this object emitted when it began the journey would take 100 years to reach our eyes. By then, it would be pretty close to Earth already and only has 1 more light year to go, which it can cover in 0.1 year. My question is, from our perspective, would it seem as if the object only took 0.1 year to cover the entire journey from start to finish?

Comment: Unless you are saying that the object is suddenly accelerated from rest to zooming at us, the standard SR understanding is that the object was already approaching us at 0.99c from time immemorial, and that means that we would have been seeing that it was approaching us all the time.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superluminal_motion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the object turned on its headlights when passing a milestone 100 light years away in the Earth's frame, then the object would arrive at Earth not long after you had first seen its blue-shifted headlights, so if you naively assumed the time difference was how long it had taken the object to cover the distance, you would mistakenly conclude it had been travelling faster than light.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any surprise or contradiction here. Imagine that you were looking with a super-duper telescope at that object and see it 100 light-years away turning on its engines. At that point you know that **100 years ago** it turned on its engines. When next year it arrives in earth, you won't be surprised - after all, you know it has already been traveling for 100 years (you didn't know this two years ago, but you know it now).

If the object was travelling at exactly the speed of light, earth would be even more surprised - the object would arrive with absolutely no advance warning - there would be no way to know that the object has left its home planet before it suddenly arrives on earth. In Katie Mack's book "The End of Everything", which discusses all sorts of (physics) way in which the universe can end, one potential catastrophe (the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_vacuum_decay) is particularly scary because it moves through the universe at the speed of light, destroying everything it reaches but with absolutely no advance warning - even if we had the best telescopes imaginable we couldn't know that this destruction front is coming, because it is coming at the speed of light and no information about it can move faster.